# What is bluetooth le multi advertising?

Tags: bluetooth, ads, bluetooth-lowenergy

I couldn't find a clear explanation what  is Bluetooth le multi advertising.

For example, in Specification of the Bluetooth System, I see only 
description of BLE advertising but not multi advertising.

What the difference between BLE advertising and multi advertising?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

LE Multi advertising refers to a specific offload (non bluetooth specification) feature that has been implemented in the Android releases by Google, starting from the L release.
What multi advertising means is, that your Android phone or a device with Android stack, can enable multiple advertisement trains at the same time. For instance, one specific app can set certain advertisement data (example supported services etc.), advertisement parameters and enable advertisement, and so can N number of other apps, on the same device.
At the hardware level (or physical layer), these advertisement trains are interleaved between the three advertisement channels (37, 38, 39) and thus your phone behaves as multiple peripheral devices at the same time. All these advertisement trains also have a separate Random private address, so they are seen distinctly by the remote scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Smart has two ways of communicating. The first one is using advertisements, where a BLE peripheral device broadcasts packets to every device around it. The receiving device can then act on this information or connect to receive more information. The second way to communicate is to receive packets using a connection, where both the peripheral and central send packets. We will focus on advertisement for several reasons:

You can’t create a connection between two devices without using advertisements. Defining the data and format of advertisement packets is usually the first thing you work on when developing a BLE device.
A large number of BLE products sleep most of the time, waking up only to advertise and connect when needed. This means advertisements have a big impact on power consumption.
Users want responsive products, and the advertising interval is critical in quick connections.
Advertising is by design unidirectional. A Central device can’t send any data to the Peripheral device without a connection. But a single peripheral can advertise to multiple masters in the area.

ref:http://www.argenox.com/bluetooth-low-energy-ble-v4-0-development/library/a-ble-advertising-primer/

Comment: This answer only describes advertising, it doesn't describe "multiple advertising" as asked in the question.  The only reference to multiplicity is in saying that an advertisement (even just a single advertisement) can be received by "multiple masters in the area".